# Fortran Type mismatch in argument n at 1 passed REAL(8) to integer (4)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm having a problem with a fortran 77 project (Yes i know it's archaic, but my prof requres us to program in fixed form fortran)

So I'm having a problem with a subroutine, which should read an N dimension Vector, which should be a column. the code for this looks like: (its still an early draft for my homework, just trying to figure out how to call a subroutine the rest of the code will be done if i can compile this problem)

```
Program gauss
implicit double precision (A-H,O-Z)
!he directly asked for implicit typing 
call Vread(V(N))
end program



Subroutine Vread(V,N)
Implicit double precision (A-H,O-Z)
dimension V(N)
read(*,*) (V(I),I=1,N)
return
end
```

So my problem is: If I try to compile it with `gfortran gauss.exe -o gauss.f` the compiler returns with error:

```
Type mismatch argument 'n' at(1); passed REAL(8) to Integer(4)
```

Comment: the most glaring issue here is `n` is never assigned a value anywhere..  I don't believe that error comes from that code. As written the code should send the linker off looking for a function called `v` and throw an error related to that.

Answer (score 4):

In your main program you write

```
call Vread(V(N))  ! this passes a rank-1 vector with N elements
```

but your subroutine is declared

```
Subroutine Vread(V,N)  ! this requires 2 arguments
```

Change the call to

```
call Vread(V,N)
```

and let your professor know that the 21st Century arrived a while age.  Note too that it is possible to write 21C Fortran in fixed-form.  It doesn't make much sense, but might enable you to toe the line while developing in a more modern version of the language.

```
!he directly asked for implicit typing
```

I trust that you are in a jurisdiction where you do not pay directly for your education.  If you are paying fees then demand more, you're being cheated.

Comment: call Vread(V(N)) doesn't this pass the "address" of V(N) and it is interpreted in the subroutine as an array "starting" at element N (due to the call)?

Comment: Yes, but in the executable code, V(N) is a single element, presumably the last element if N is the size of the array. The standard way to send an entire array is with its name without any indices, hence: `call Vread(V,N)`. I'm a professor and require Fortran too but I require that they use `implicit none` and explicitly declare all variables (and I have been called archaic).

Comment: For me the important point in my remark was to make the comment clear as now the suggestion is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but if i change it to call Vread(V,N) i get Error: invalid procedure argument at (1) error

Comment: V is not declared as an array by the implicit statement but as a scalar. You have to explicitly set the size of the array or make a pointer or allocatable out of it and allocate the array (your prof won't like it as it is to new. Fortran 90 ;-) ).

Comment: The argument `V(N)` to the subroutine `Vread` isn't a rank-1 array, it's (implicitly) a double precision function result of `V` with argument (implicitly) default integer and implicit interface.

Comment: @albert, `V` in the main program is a function.

Comment: @francescalus You are right, even more confusing certainly for the novice users.